# SSH into Raspberry Pi on IPv6 network

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, ipv6

First of all: I am a network noob, so excuse the noobness of my question.

I want to SSH from my Mac into my Raspberry Pi within my local network. I have an IPv6 network and cannot change to IPv4 because of my ISP.

The Pi has an internet connection, I can load websites. But I cannot ping anything (I used all combinations of `ping` and `ping6` and `google.com` and `ipv6.google.com`. There is absolutely no output and if I press Ctrl-C, it says something like "X packets transmitted, 0 received". Same thing when I ping my Mac.

I tried using `ip address` on the Pi and pinging the two wlan0-IPv6 addresses from my Mac. One didn't work at all ("X packets transmitted, 0 received"), the other started printing

```
ping6: sendmsg: No route to host
ping6: wrote fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d 16 chars, ret=-1
```

over and over again.

I tried `ip -6 route` on the Pi and got

```
2a02:8070:da1:c700::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 303 mtu 1500 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::362c:c4ff:fe4e:3c16 dev wlan0 metric 303 mtu 1500 pref medium
```

When I ping **2a02:8070:da1:c700** from my Mac, I actually get a response, but using SSH to connect to this address does not work. When I ping **fe80::362c:c4ff:fe4e:3c16**, I get the same "no route to host" messages.

SSH does not work at all, naturally, since I cannot ping anything in this shitty network. But SSH is my ultimate goal. Pls help me :)

Comment: `fe80:` addresses are link-local, so you generally need to specify which link they belong to. On the Mac, try `ping6 fe80::362c:c4ff:fe4e:3c16%en0` (assuming `en0` is the interface connected to the network the Pi is on). But that's going to ping the router, not the Pi; to find the Pi's addresses (it'll generally have several), run `ip -6 address` or `ifconfig wlan0` on it, then try `ping6`ing them from the Mac (adding the `%en0` for the `fe80:` one). BTW, `2a02:8070:da1:c700` is a network *prefix* (i.e. the hosts on that net will have addresses that start with that), not any specific host.

Comment: Pi output: `1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a02:8070:da1:c700:63f5:4e71:fc9f:b24b/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 169792sec preferred_lft 83392sec
    inet6 fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
When I try pinging **fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d%wlan0** from my Mac, I get "no route to host" again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `wlan0` is an interface name on your Pi; the Mac has no idea what it is. On the Mac, you need to use the Mac's interface name, which is probably something like `en0` -- run `ifconfig -a` on the Mac to get a list of its interfaces and their associated addresses (note: there'll be a bunch of irrelevant ones that you can ignore, like `gif0`, `p2p0`, `awdl0`, etc). On the Mac, try `ping6 fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d%en0` and `ping6 2a02:8070:da1:c700:63f5:4e71:fc9f:b24b` (although the second is a temporary address; for privacy reasons it'll be changed every day or so).

Comment: Yes, it seams to be `en0` on the Mac, but neither one of the pings you suggested went through. I get 100% package loss in both cases :(

Comment: It sounds like you may have something blocking pings on your network; pings are sometimes used for network attacks, so some paranoid firewalls & other network gear will block them. Try a "real" network conection instead: from the Mac, try `ssh pi@fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d%en0`

Comment: Also, check the neighbor discovery table on the Mac to see if it's been able to discover the Pi's hardware address. Run `ndp -an` on the Mac, and see if "fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d%en0" is listed.

Comment: SSH is my ultimate goal, I just thought pinging would be the first step of debugging this problem... The Pi can ping itself though. When I try to SSH I get `ssh: connect to host fe80::8ee5:58db:42c:2d9d%en0 port 22: Operation timed out`. I looked at the neighbor discovery table and the Pi's address doesn't show at all.

Comment: Are you sure they're both on the same local network? How exactly are things connected up?

Comment: They are both connected to the same WiFi network. The Pi uses a WiFi dongle for that, since it's Gen-1. The Mac uses the built-in WiFi module. The setup used to work on my old network with IPv4 but since I moved and am now forced to use IPv6 because of my new ISP, I cannot connect... I cannot use the IPv4 addresses both of the devices obviously have either (maybe there is a way to make that work?)

Comment: I'm really confused about what's happening here; it really sounds like the two computers aren't on the same net. Do the network settings on the Mac match those on the Pi? Specifically, run `route get -inet6 2600::` on the Mac, and see if it lists "`gateway: fe80::362c:c4ff:fe4e:3c16%en0`" (the same default router address you got from `ip -6 route` on the Pi), and run `ifconfig en0` and see if the "inet6" addresses it lists (other than the "`fe80::`" one) start with the same "`2a02:8070:da1:c700:`" prefix the Pi's public address has?

Comment: The router address matches, as well as the prefix. I am confused as well...

Comment: Ok, fallback question: do they each have link-local (169.254.x.x) IPv4 addresses they can talk to each other over? Check `ifconfig en0` on the Mac, and `ip addr` on the Pi.

Comment: Yes they do have IPv4 addresses, except it's 192.168.0.X. But they cannot communicate over it. When I ping Mac -> Pi, I get `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` etc. If I try to SSH Mac -> Pi, I get `ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: No route to host`. If I ping Pi -> Mac, I get `From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable` etc. Do I have to specify ports in some way?

Comment: At this point, I'm completely stumped. As I said, ping sometimes gets blocked for security reasons, but if `ndp` doesn't work (for hosts on the same network segment), you aren't going to be able to communicate with IPv6. At all. (Same with arp for IPv4.) Something is very wrong, but I don't know what it is. The only thing I can suggest is to try to find a working situation (maybe putting them on a completely different network and/or replacing one or both with other devices), and then try in-between configs to isolate out what the critical failing element is.

Comment: I have the same exact issue as last @matveyfridman's comment. Did you manage to resolve? I suspect an issue with my FritzBox router, even though I changed no configuration on it.

Comment: @Kamafeather: nope, I could not resolve the issue, just abandoned the project altogether ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I've found out that my ssh client had switched wi-fi network (to the neighbours' one) after I rebooted the router. This caused my client to not reach the RasPi ssh server on my actual home wi-fi network. Silly problem, but I didn't notice that as long as I was checking IPs with `ifconfig`. Then I took a look at my WiFi connected network and slapped myself. However the symptoms and diagnostic was weirdly the same as yours. Thanks for giving updates tho.